# How do I "undo" merging a specific change set in svn

Tags: svn, merge, revert

I have the following scenario.

1) Get a local copy of a repo.

2) Undo a change set I don't want (revision 120).
 svn merge -c -120 .

3) Do my work modifying files.

4) Now I want to "undo" what I did in (2) without undoing all my changes from (3). Is that possible with svn?

BTW, I'm using Subversion version 1.5.2, in case that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can `svn merge -c 120`. This will exactly undo `svn merge -c -120`, done in (2).

Comment: That's what I thought. But it does not. In fact it appears to do nothing. (BTW, I'm using Subversion command-line client, version 1.5.2, don't know if that matters...)

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `svn merge -c -X` on the revision created in (2). If by (3) you mean you have changes in the working tree that are not committed, you can do something like this:

```
 svn diff >saved.diff
 svn revert -R .
 svn merge -c -X
 patch -p0 <saved.diff
```

Comment: Yes, I mean I have changes in my working tree that are not committed.

Comment: Wouldn't saved.diff contain my desired changes AND the changes from step (2)? Therefore I think these 4 commands would end up putting me right back where I was.

Comment: You are right, I haven't realized you haven't committed the merge.